# Creating a custom FactoryBean in Sprint Boot 2.3/Spring 5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javabeans, autowired

I've got a spring-boot web application that's mostly working; my DataSource is properly configured by an external `application.properties` file.

Now I want to add properties to that file to help me instantiate and configure two instances of a class in my app. I have a `APNsFactory` that I currently instantiate manually and configure using JNDI, but I want to get away from JNDI calls:

```java
    @Bean
    public
    APNsFactory
    apnsFactory()
        throws
            javax.naming.NamingException
    {
        sLogger.info("Configuring APNsFactory");

        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

        APNsFactory f = new APNsFactory();
        f.setProductionKeystorePath((String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/apns/prod/keystorePath"));
        f.setProductionKeystorePassword((String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/apns/prod/keystorePassword"));
        f.setDevelopmentKeystorePath((String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/apns/dev/keystorePath"));
        f.setDevelopmentKeystorePassword((String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/apns/dev/keystorePassword"));
        return f;
    }
```

When running before in a standalone webapp container, Spring properly called that method and the JNDI context from the container’s `<env-entry>` tags was available.

I'm trying to update my `APNsFactory` to be a proper Spring `FactoryBean<>`, and I’ve given it a couple of `@Autowire String` variables that I want to be set by Spring Boot from the `application.properties` file.

For bonus points, I want this to be usable both in Spring Boot and in a standalone container like Tomcat or Resin.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get Spring to do this. There are dozens of examples for DataSources and other Beans already implemented by Spring, but none for a completely custom one, using `application.properties`, in a Spring Boot web environment.

I've seen some examples that use an XML config file, but I'm not sure how to do that with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a factory bean here.
You already have spring boot that can read `application.properties` out-of-the-box:

So try the following:

1. Create key/values in the `application.properties` file:

```
myapp.keystore.path=...
myapp.keystore.passwd=...
// the same for other properties
```

2. Create `ConfigurationProperties` class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="myapp.keystore")
public class MyAppKeyStoreConfigProperties {

   private String path;  // the names must match to those defined in the properties file
   private String passwd;

   ... getters, setters
}
```

3. In the class marked with `@Configuration` (the one where you create `@Bean public APNsFactory apnsFactory()`) do the following:

```
@Configuration
// Note the following annotation:
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyAppKeyStoreConfigProperties.class)
public class MyConfiguration {
   // Note the injected configuration parameter
   @Bean public APNsFactory apnsFactory(MyAppKeyStoreConfigProperties config) {
       APNsFactory f = new APNsFactory();
       f.setProductionKeystorePath(config.getKeyPath());
       and so on
   } 
}
```

I've intentionally didn't show the separation between production/dev stuff.
In spring boot you have profiles so that the same artifact (WAR, JAR whatever) can be configured to run with different profile and depending on that the corresponding properties will be read.

Example:

If you're running with `prod` profile, then in addition to `application.properties` that will be loaded anyway, you can put these `keystore` related definitions to `application-prod.properties` (the suffix matches the profile name) - spring boot will load those automatically. The same goes for `dev` profile of course.

Now I haven't totally understand the "bonus points" task :) This mechanism is spring boot proprietary way of dealing with configuration. In "standalone" server it should still have a WAR with spring boot inside so it will use this mechanism anyway. Maybe you can clarify more, so that I / our colleagues could provide a better answer

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I'm not yet sure how I'll make this work in a standalone container, but I'll burn that bridge when I get to it.

A couple notes; I used `@ComponentScan` on my `AppConfig` class, specifying a class in the package that contains my ConfigurationProperties class. And I named my setters/getters appropriately to match the `.properties file`, didn't have to name the fields in any special way.

Lastly, the prod/dev is a runtime decision made, so both have to be configured, but I handled that.